# UCube USB speaker stop working after sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, sleep, speakers

I can "fix" this issue by pluging out the USB cable and plug it in again after waking my PC up from sleep mode. But doing this after EVERY time I put my PC into sleep mode is kind of tiring. Neither UCube nor Microsoft support were actually helpful on this...

Is there maybe a x-mas miracle that would solve this issue? Can I immitate the usb plug in/out via software?

Happy Holidays!

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

**BIOS Version 2.00.1201 (2012)**
[image]

---

System log
[image]

---

Comment: I even disabled selective USB energy saving mode

Comment: Workaround: buy a USB hub with buttons that electronically let you disconnect/reconnect USB devices w/o wearing down USB ports

Comment: @gregg Makes sense in general, however, pluging the cable out and in became such a habbit that I think will not be improved by a switch...

Answer (score 1):

In the post
[No sound from session on login screen after sleep. Changed after 1809](https://www.tenforums.com/sound-audio/132632-no-sound-session-login-screen-after-sleep-changed-after-1809-a-post1666832.html#post1666832),
the solution was to run as Administrator the following code:

```
sc stop Audiosrv
sc config Audiosrv obj= "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" password= ""
sc start Audiosrv
```

If these commands when run in a Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator,
succeed in restoring the functioning of your device, then as a workaround you
could paste them into a `.bat` file and use the Task Scheduler to
create a new task with highest privileges to run at logon of any user
and after sleep.

Comment: Thanks, this would have been an elegant solution. However, it doesn't work with my uCube speakers I'm afraid...

Comment: (1) Do the other speakers work after sleep? (2) Try *Start > Troubleshooting > Troubleshoot audio playback*.

Comment: When I enter the first command, I get an error message saying something like "A stop sign was sent to a service, which other services depend on"

Comment: Yes, other speakers work after sleep mode - however, the working speakers are powered directly (and not via USB like the uCubes)

Comment: The UCube device might have problems when powered down & up, so perhaps you should keep it from sleeping (or let it sleep if it doesn't now). Here are two helpful links: [link1](https://www.top-password.com/blog/set-windows-to-power-on-off-usb-devices-in-sleep-mode/) and possibly also [link2](https://www.urtech.ca/2015/10/solved-my-dell-laptop-does-not-charge-usb-devices-when-it-goes-to-sleep/).

Comment: Thanks, however, I have quite a lot USB controllers, how do I know which one I need to configure?

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1619031/8672) of mine.

Comment: OK, I used the USB Device Tree Viewer and checked - energy save mode is unchecked for this USB device. Also, my ASUS BIOS does not have the settings available as mentioned in link2. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. So I guess, this is it?

Comment: The only thing I found out. When I connect my mobile phone to the PC. When I start sleep mode, the phone stops loading. It only continues loading (while the PC stays in sleep mode) when I plug it out and in again.

Comment: This is strange. Are you using the latest BIOS? What is the computer model?

Comment: In Services.msc, double-click Windows Audio, Recovery (tab), are the top three drop-downs 'Restart the Service'? Does Event Viewer Application or System logs show _Audiosrv_ service failing after coming back from sleep?

Comment: @harrymc I have quite an old motherboard, I guess: ASUS Crosshair IV Extreme, AMD 890FX, AM3, CF X, Fuzion

Comment: @gregg I added a screenshot of the Windows Audio settings in my description (*before* letting the PC sleep). However, I'm not sure what you mean with the second part of your question, how can I look that up?

Comment: @harrymc I added the BIOS infos to the description

Comment: @gregg I added a screenshot of the system logs after coming back from sleep mode to the description

Comment: There is a later [BIOS version 3027](https://www.asus.com/in/supportonly/Crosshair%20IV%20Extreme/HelpDesk_Download/), a month later than yours. It might help, although a beta version.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, however, this issue is not that big that I would take the risk of system stability because of a beta version. Also, it says that it support new CPUs, so I assume this is all the change there is to it. If it would just improve things, it wouldn't be a beta.

Comment: It was beta in 2011... But I understand your being reticent about a BIOS update. One more idea is to have a look at the Event Viewer error by "Service Control Manager" or any others for perhaps a hint. And the last idea is to run [powercfg -energy](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html) and post the resulting file for us to have a look.

Comment: @harrymc OK, I can create a powercfg report. Do you need it in general or especially after coming back from sleep mode?

Comment: A general report is OK. BTW, you wasted your bounty.

Comment: @harrymc I added the report to the description. Sorry about the bounty, I wasn't aware it got wasted...

Comment: Please, not as an image. Impossible to copy-paste from am image.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't upload an HTML, and in plain text it is even less readable. Can I email it to you perhaps?

Comment: No, don't bother. I can't read it, anyway.

Comment: I could translate it to English...