# How to identify faulty USB device based on USBDeviceViewer?

Tags: windows-10, usb

I operate Win 10, with a multitude of black, blue and red USB ports. I have about 30 connected USB devices for a specific use-case. Occasionally, I get a message stating that a connected device was not recognized.

After installing the Win SDK and opening the USB Device viewer, I get the following message: (I translated the first line into English, so the exact wording might differ)

```
[Port2] FailedEnumeration :  Unknown USB-Device (Error resetting the port.)


Is Port User Connectable:         yes
Is Port Debug Capable:            no
Companion Port Number:            2
Companion Hub Symbolic Link Name: USB#VID_05E3&PID_0610#7&1406ab05&0&4#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}
Protocols Supported:
 USB 1.1:                         no
 USB 2.0:                         no
 USB 3.0:                         yes

       ---===>Device Information<===---

ConnectionStatus:                  FailedEnumeration
Current Config Value:              0x00  -> Device Bus Speed: SuperSpeed
Device Address:                    0x00
Open Pipes:                           0
*!*ERROR:  No open pipes!

          ===>Device Descriptor<===
*!*ERROR:  bLength of 0 incorrect, should be 18
bLength:                           0x00
bDescriptorType:                   0x00
bcdUSB:                          0x0000
bDeviceClass:                      0x00
*!*ERROR:  Device enumeration failure
```

Does this message, or more precisely the serial, provide any information to identify the faulty device? As far as I can tell, every device works, but with random failures, all over the place. As a side note, all my hubs are powered.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that USB Device Viewer loses the device name when a disconnection occurs. Why don't you create a map of all the ports and their devices? This will allow you to identify the device by its hub&port number.

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks. I might plug them in one by one. Are names like "Port 4" constantly assigned to specific hardware plugs, or are they assigned dynamically?

Comment: The port numbers are hardwired and don't change. When the device is connected, you can either see its name directly in USB Device Viewer on the port, or in the detailed info pane. This would be simpler than plugging them in turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool to see all connected USB devices is [USBTreeViewer](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview.html) by Uwe Sieber, which is a derivative from open-license Microsoft DDK tool. An example of a view:

[image]

If a USB device malfunctions, you will see a yellow mark over the failed port, with possible explanation (driver error code).

If you have a problem with USB devices, it is advisable to establish a map of PC ports to port numbers in USBTreeView (and different host controllers) first, by sticking handwritten lables on PC panels/ports, as harrymc suggests. Then you will know which one of devices fails by examining port status in the viewer. Keep in mind that the same physical receptacle (of USB3 type) will be mapped to two different ports, one for SS (USB3) connection, and the other for USB2.